# JavaScript loop printing a HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, loops, foreach

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="content">   

<article class="underline">
        <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"  
         src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>
        <h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit"></a></h2>
        <p id="desc">Esse buraco na rua Montes Claros já está há 1 ano 
         trazendo transtornos aos moradores</p><p></p>
        <div class="date" id="date"></div>
        <img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">
        <img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">

</article>
```

And this ajax that receive an array:

```
$.ajax({

  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost/again/www/index.php",
  dataType: "json",

    success: function (data) {

        var tit = "";
        // Loop over each object
        for (var $i = 0; $i < data.length; $i++) {
            var object = data[$i];

            tit+=  object.titulo;


        }
              $('#tit').html(tit);
     }
    });

</script>
```

Now, it is inserting everything in the same HTML code(off course,because I don't have a foreach), but I would like to show this HTML for each row(each "tit") that i am receiving...Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you wanting to generate a new article block for each result?

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode yes, exactly what I want. Generate a new article for each result...

Comment: Can you paste in an example of the JSON that gets returned in your $.ajax function?

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode  My ajax is receiving a Json array like this: [{"codigo":"32","0":"32","titulo":"Some title here","1":"Some title here","descricao":"Here is my description","2":"Here is my description","data":"2015-10-29 21:48:13","3":"2015-10-29 21:48:13"l},{"codigo":"33","0":"33","titulo":Title here,"1":title here,"descricao":description here,"2":description here,"data":"2015-10-30 20:45:46","3":"2015-10-30 20:45:46"}]

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode For each title I would like to generate an article...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is this: You have an array with text that you want to loop through, and display.

If this was your array:

```
["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5"]
```

then you want this to be displayed

```
<element>Text 1</element>
<element>Text 2</element>
<element>Text 3</element>
<element>Text 4</element>
<element>Text 5</element>
```

#### The problem in your code

The problem I see in your code is that you are using jquery's `.html(arrayItem)` which will overwrite any existing text inside of the element.

Instead look at my solution: (http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/v6upsLp8/)

HTML

```
<div id="tit"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tit = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5"];

    for (var i in tit) {
        var element = document.createElement("h2");
        element.innerHTML = tit[i];
        $("#tit").append(element);
    }
});
```

over here we use jQuery's `.append`, and we create a `node` and we append the `node` into the wrapper element.

### If you have any questions, please leave a comment below and I will reply ASAP

Comment: Thanks, but no, it is only printing the title and I would like to print for each title(<h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit"></a></h2>) a picture( <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"  src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>), a description(that is -><p id="desc">Esse buraco na rua Montes Claros já está há 1 ano trazendo transtornos aos moradores</p>), a date(<div class="date" id="data"><span>20 mar 2012</span></div>) and other 2 small pictures(that are in "img/no-tick.png and"img/apoio.png">). Understand?

Comment: Same concept... just multiply the for loops to satisfy each of the given criteria

Comment: But, how can I do loop with things that didn't come from my DB, things that are in my html, like <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente" src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a> that I want to repeat for each titulo(title)?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("elementsClassName")`... That will return an `array` with all of your elements. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to keep things organised is to use a templating engine like handlebars. I've set up a jsfiddle for you that renders out your articles using the example data you provided (which needed a bit of formatting to get working).

http://jsfiddle.net/4ud6rLfq/10/

```
// This is what you'll need to get the data via AJAX
var source   = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/again/www/index.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#articles').append(template(value));
        });
    }
});

// A demo using the data you provided (formatted a bit)
var data = [
    {
        "codigo":"32",
        "titulo":"Some title here",
        "descricao":"Here is my description",
        "data":"2015-10-29 21:48:13"
    },{
        "codigo":"33",
        "titulo":"Title here",
        "descricao":"description here",
        "data":"2015-10-30 20:45:46"
    }
];

var source   = $("#template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#articles').append(template(value));
});
```

And the HTML you'll need:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <article class="underline">
        <a href="#">
             <img class="incidente" src="" alt="{{titulo}}" />
        </a>
        <h2><a href="#">{{titulo}}</a></h2>
        <p class="desc">{{descricao}}</p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="date" class="date">{{data}}</div>
        <img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">
        <img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">
    </article>
</script>

<div id="articles"></div>
```

There's an example using your $.ajax function commented out and another example below it using the data variable - all you need to do is include handlebars in your page after jQuery and it should be good to go. You can edit the variables in the template to match whatever you pass back to your script via ajax.

Basically what's happening is your setting up the template for your data first, then you loop over your data and bind each item to the template, the item template is then appended to the #articles container as HTML and it moves on to the next item until it's finished.

Comment: +1 for offering a simple method but -1 for using multiple id's of similar value, Nah, just kidding. But only kidding about the -1, not about teh id's!

Comment: I am trying to insert Handlebars, but there is an error -> Error: GET http://localhost/connect/www/js/handlebars-v4.0.4.js

Comment: Ok, now I solved the problem to get handlebars archive. But now nothing is appering on my screen... :/ I don't receiving any error..

Comment: @AmandaPistolato did you add a new div with id="articles" where you want your articles to appear?

Comment: @AmandaPistolato can you put the page online somewhere so I can check it out?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you have multiple articles and you want to change their titles dynamically?

If so, first of all you should remove;

`$('#tit').html(tit);`

Then inside the loop put this:

`$('#content article:eq('+$i+')').find('#tit').html(object.titulo);`

This works only if `$i` is the same as the elements index relative to their parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which returns a string with the html-markup. If you need to populate the html-template then you will need to send params to that function. Here is an example of the javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/fnLjcfvr/1/

```
function getHtml(title){
    var html = "";
    html += '<div class="content">';
    html += '';
    html += '<article class="underline">';
    html += '<a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"';  
    html += 'src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>';
    html += '<h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit"> + ' title ' + </a></h2>';
    html += '<p id="desc">Esse buraco na rua Montes Claros já está há 1 ano          trazendo transtornos aos moradores</p><p></p>';
    html += '<div class="date" id="date"></div>';
    html += '<img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">';
    html += '<img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">';
    html += '';
    html += '</article>';

    return html;
}
```